# Move data from ViewModel to Fragment using RxJava

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, android-livedata

I'm trying to build app using MVVM architecture.
But I don't know how to move value from ViewModel to Fragment when this value has been downloaded using RxJava.

At the moment I have this code and I don't have idea how to do it.
Could someone help ?

in fragment:

```
viewModel.loadListOfCats().observe(this, Observer {
                it?.let {
                    listOfCats.clear()
                    listOfCats.addAll(it.listOfCats)
                    catAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            })
```

in ViewModel:

```
fun loadListOfCats(): LiveData<ListOfCats>{
        compositeDisposable.add(listOfQuizzesRepository.getListOfCats()
            .subscribeWith(object: DisposableSingleObserver<ListOfCats>(){
                override fun onSuccess(t: ListOfCats) {
                    val listOfCats= t

                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {

                }

            }))
        return ?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rx done works by async process, not sync process. That's mean when this function comes to `return ?`, Rx hasn't finished its work yet.

So that you can't return the value got from Rx at the end of function.

You have to set value in its onSuccess and onError callback.

```
class YourViewModel {
    val listCats = MutableLiveData<ListOfCats>()

    fun loadListOfCats() {
        ...
            override fun onSuccess(t: ListOfCats) {
                listCats.value = t
            }
        ...
    }
}

class YourFragment {
    ...
    viewModel.listCats.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let {
            ...
        }
    })
}
```